# Android Automotive. "No system images available " for Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android-automotive

I'm usig Android Studio 4.0. When I want to create AVD for Automotive, I don't see any available system images. I was trying to change update channel , but it doesn't lead to success.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. Changing update channel alone didn't help me either. However System Image became available after installing and running Android Studio 4.2 Preview